# Free physics library?

Tags: c#, xna, physics, xna-4.0

What are some good recommendations?  I have a vertex buffer and indices and I want to be able to detect collision between it and a bounding box or another object.

Comment: Polling or opinion/recommendation type questions aren't typically suited for this site. What have you tried? It also seems it would be much easier if you had a bounding box defined for your buffered object instead of trying to compare directly to a buffered object.